# Get json data and put it into a variable

Tags: c#, json, wpf, visual-studio-2015

I have a project where I need to get data with json and then put it into a datagrid.

this is how I get the data:

```
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
     string email = loginDialog.email;
     string password = loginDialog.password;

     WebClient http = new WebClient();

     http.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
     http.Headers.Add("OSLC-Core-Version", "2.0");

     //Windows login: Email + Password
     http.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(email, password);
     using(Stream stream = http.OpenRead(stringURL))
     {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(stream);
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
        //Console.WriteLine(json);
     }
}
```

Here I get the json data... How can I now put the data(just the priority) in a Variable?

```
// priority = 
// BTQStatus = 
// implementationDate =
```

Comment: `var json` contains XML or JSON?

Comment: You can deserialize the `JSON` / `XML`.

Comment: @aloisdg var json contains XML.

Comment: @Tomi Why you want to use json? Why not use directly the xml? Can you share the XML with us?

Comment: @aloisdg it's easier to read.

Comment: @Tomi Why you want to read it? For the debug? Your program is going to read it not an human, isn't it? You just have to deserialize your string downloaded to a class.

Comment: @aloisdg You're right! Now I have this:  
 ` using(Stream stream = http.OpenRead(StringUrl))
          {
               XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
               doc.Load(stream);
               string json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
               //Console.WriteLine(json);
            }`

How can I now GET the data I want and PUT it into a VARIABLE?

Comment: Please @Tomi forget about json here. Just serialize your xml to an object. Can you share your xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you know the type of the class you are going to load, consider using the NUGET package NewtonSoft.Json.

When using this package converting to object to and from a JSON string is done in one statement.

Example:

- Use Visual Studio to create a Console Application JSonSaveLoad
- Install NewtonSoft.Json:
- In solution explorer, right click on references of your project and select Manage NUGET packages.
- search for Json.Net and install it

Create a class with some simple properties:

```
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime BirthDay { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DeathDay { get; set; }
    }
```

Converting to and from JSon is done as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // fill a list with Persons and Pupils
    var personalHeroes = new List<Person>()
    {
        new Person()
        {
            Name = "Charley Chaplin",
            BirthDay = new DateTime(1890, 8, 4),
            DeathDay = new DateTime(1977, 12, 25),
        },
        new Person()
        {
            Name = "Winston Churchill",
            BirthDay = new DateTime(1885, 4, 18),
            DeathDay = new DateTime(1965, 01,24),
        },
        new Person()
        {
            Name = "Pope Franciscus",
            BirthDay = new DateTime(1936, 12, 17)
            // not Death yet!
        },
    };

    // JSON serialize to file, also write result to screen
    var tmpFileName = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
    using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(tmpFileName))
    {
        string jsonTxt = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(personalHeroes , Formatting.Indented);
        Console.WriteLine(jsonTxt);
        writer.Write(jsonTxt);
    }

    // deserialize
    using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(tmpFileName))
    {
        var jsonTxt = reader.ReadToEnd();
        var deserializedHeroes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(jsonTxt);
    }
    File.Delete(tmpFileName);
}
```

Comment: I'm using Newtonsoft.json; 
Where do you get (serializedP) from?

Comment: oops, my fault. I corrected it. The deserialization is done from the read string to the object of the type you specify: JSonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(string) will return an object of type T if the string contains the Json representation of it. Only disadvantage: you have to have access to the type definition of T

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers! I found a solution:

```
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
    string email = loginDialog.email;
    string password = loginDialog.password;



    webClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    webClient.Headers.Add("OSLC-Core-Version", "2.0");

    //Windows login: Email + Password
    webClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(email, password);
    using (Stream stream = webClient.OpenRead(URLstring)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(stream);
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);

        JObject searchResult = JObject.Parse(json);
        if (searchResult.GetValue("oslc_cm:totalCount").Value<int>() == 1) {
        using (Stream BTQStream = webClient.OpenRead(searchResult.SelectToken("oslc_cm:results").First.SelectToken("rdf:resource").Value<String>()))
        {
           XmlDocument BTQdoc = new XmlDocument();
           BTQdoc.Load(BTQStream);
           string BTQJson = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(BTQdoc);
           JObject BTQEntry = JObject.Parse(BTQJson);
           priority = BTQEntry.SelectToken("Severity.oslc_cm:label").Value<String>();
           BTQStatus = BTQEntry.GetValue("State").Value<String>();
           implementationDate = Convert.ToDateTime(BTQEntry.GetValue("actualdate_impl").Value<String>());
        }
        }
    }
```

}

Now it gets the Data from `URLstring` and put it into a dataGrid.